# get first three letters of a word in php

Tags: php

i would like to get the first three letters of a word in php.

for example:

i have september 5, 2012 in my database (mysql)

and in my html i only want to see the first three letters of the date like in september i want it to be "SEP" only in my html.

and what if i want to get the 5, and 2012?

thanks for your answers but how to get the 5 and 2012? i mean the day and the year

Comment: [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)?

Comment: try `strtotime` and `date`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use substr function

```
$date = "September 5, 2012";
$final_date = substr($date, 0, 3);
echo $final_date;
```

to grab day and year from the date use

```
//day
$day = date("d", strtotime($date));
//year
$year = date("Y", strtotime($date));
```

Now you can use these 3 variables.

Comment: thanks your code works perfectly. one more question is how can i get the 5 and 2012 from the date?

Comment: // for day $day = date("d", strtotime($date)); & for year $year = date("Y", strtotime($date));

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Something like:

```
$dateStr = "september 5, 2012";
$month = date("M", strtotime($dateStr)); //Sep
$day = date("d", strtotime($dateStr)); //05
$year = date("Y", strtotime($dateStr)); //2012
```

Or of course:

```
$dateStr = "september 5, 2012";
$completeDateVariable = date("M jS Y", strtotime($dateStr)); //Sep 5th 2012
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str='abcdef';

echo substr($str,0,3);
```